# Javascript: passing constructor arguments down the prototype chain. Is there a way?

Tags: javascript

In the following example, is there a way to construct the object such that “b” has a property a1, initialised to “2”?

```
function A(a1) {
    this.a1 = a1;
}

function B(b1, a1) {
    this.b1 = b1;
}

B.prototype = new A;

var b = new B('1', '2');
```

I am basically trying to duplicate what would be known as “calling the base constructor” in a traditional object orientated language (such as c#).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this?

```
function B(b1, a1) {
    A.call(this, a1);
    this.b1 = b1;
}
```

Comment: That works.  It will call A's constructor twice (once because of the line: B.prototype = new A;).  I now wonder if I need the "B.prototype = new A;" line at all, since I never use instanceof.  Thanks.